# Отключить скрипты или удалить часть кода из родительской темы

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Скрипт шаблона wordpress нужному мне элементу присваивает свой стиль.
Тема дочерняя. Можно ли через functions отключить скрипты или удалить часть кода из родительской темы?

Comment: Если родительская тема это позволяет, то можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно

[wp_deregister_script](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_deregister_script)

[wp_deregister_style](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_deregister_style)

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'pp_deregister_javascript', 99 );

function pp_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'name-script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'pp_deregister_styles', 99 );

function pp_deregister_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'name-style' );
}
```